# XLWINGS: How to select an entire column without headers?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

How do I go about selecting an entire column from excel without the headers?

For example, when I try the following code, it selects the entire column including the header:

import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book.caller()
wb.sheets[0].range('A:A').options(ndim=1).value

How do I select the entire column A without including the header? I basically want to use xlwings to receive values from each cell of a column from the beginning of that column till its last value (not including the header).

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: If the value returned is a list, then `wb = xw.Book.caller() wb.sheets[0].range('A:A').options(ndim=1).value[1:]` would work. I don't know xlwings, but I'd think that `wb = xw.Book.caller() wb.sheets[0].range('A2:A1000000').options(ndim=1).value` would get the first million values (of course it might give tou several hundred thousand trailing empty values, in which case my first suggestion might be better).  Anything else would involve making a selection covering the range you want, then selecting that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly slice the Range object (you don't need to declare the dimension as 1d arrays arrive per default als simple lists):

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
wb.sheets[0].range('A:A')[1:].value
```

Alternatively, define an Excel Table Object (`Insert > Table`):

```
wb.sheets[0].range('Table1[[#Data]]').value
```

This will automatically exclude the headers, see e.g. [here](https://peltiertech.com/structured-referencing-excel-tables/) for the syntax.